# How to give validator for floating point number in zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Following is the piece of code which has been taken from form,

```
$debit_amount = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('debit_amount', array(
                    'label' => 'Debit_amount',
                    'value' => '',
                    'class' => 'text-size text',
                    'required' => true,
                    'tabindex' => '13',
                    'validators' => array(
                        array('Digits', false, array(
                                'messages' => array(
                                    'notDigits' => "Invalid entry, ex. 10.00",
                                    'digitsStringEmpty' => "",
                            ))),
                        array('notEmpty', true, array(
                                'messages' => array(
                                    'isEmpty' => 'Debit_amount can\'t be empty'
                                )
                        )),

                    ),
                    'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
                    //'decorators' => $this->requiredElementDecorators,
                    //'description' => '<img src="' . $baseurl . '/images/star.png" alt="required" />',
                ));
        $this->addElement($debit_amount);
```

When i try submit the form using floating number , it throws my error "Invalid Enter....". It does not validate floating point number. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Zend_Validate_Float](http://framework.zend.com/manual/ru/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.float):

```
'validators' => array(
    array('Float', ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error message because the `Digits` validator only validates digits. There is a comment about it in the [Zend_Validate documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.digits.basic):

```
Note: Validating numbers
When you want to validate numbers or numeric values, be aware that this validator only 
validates digits. This means that any other sign like a thousand separator or a comma 
will not pass this validator. In this case you should use Zend_Validate_Int or 
Zend_Validate_Float.
```

As @Zyava says, using `Zend_Validate_Float` is the way to go.